# JS Not showing wrong result UPDATED

Tags: javascript, html

Instead of 39500 output i get 500. Could someone help me, i want IF gw reaches 0, there should be no more -500 on wall.

I used my code but it is not working.
HTML

```
<li><b>Infantry: </b><span id="gw">40000</span></li>
<p class="fort"><b>Fort: </b><span id="wall">1000</span></p>
<button class="troops" onclick="send()">SEND TROOPS</button>
```

JS

```
function send(){
    var a = document.getElementById('gw').innerHTML;
    var b = 500;
    var c = a-b;

    var label = document.getElementById('wall');
    label.innerHTML = parseInt(label.innerHTML) - b;
    var label = document.getElementById('gw');
    label.innerHTML = parseInt(label.innerHTML) - c;

}
```

Comment: `<span class= id="wall">` notice anything strange here?

Comment: In you #wall span you have a class attribute with no value, this may be making that element invalid, disallowing you from selecting it

Comment: Thank you for the first part. But after click send troops i dont get an output 39500 i get 500 and there is yet a if issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that you were doing  `var c = a-b;`, `b` being a Number, but `a` being a String (`Element.innerHTML`) - without doing `parseInt(value, radix)` on that value... and there's other math subtraction confusion in there...

**Instead:**

```js
// Helper function to set to 0 a value lower than 0
function zeroMin(val) {
  return parseInt(val, 10) < 0 ? 0 : val;
}

function send() {

  var EL_gw = document.getElementById('gw'),
    EL_wa = document.getElementById('wall'),
    gw = parseInt(EL_gw.innerHTML, 10),
    wa = parseInt(EL_wa.innerHTML, 10),
    hitVal = 500;

  // Subtract
  gw -= hitVal;
  wa -= hitVal;

  // fix to 0
  gw = zeroMin(gw);
  wa = zeroMin(wa);

  EL_gw.innerHTML = gw;
  EL_wa.innerHTML = wa;

}
```

```html
<b>Infantry:</b> <span id="gw">40000</span> <br>
<b>Fort:</b> <span id="wall">1000</span> <br>

<button class="troops" onclick="send()">SEND TROOPS</button>
```

If you want to stop any further action if **any of the values reaches 0**

```js
function send() {

  var EL_gw = document.getElementById('gw'),
      EL_wa = document.getElementById('wall'),
    gw = parseInt(EL_gw.innerHTML, 10),
    wa = parseInt(EL_wa.innerHTML, 10),
    hitVal = 500;

  if (gw <= 0 || wa <= 0) return; // Do nothing if any is <= 0 

  // else...
  gw -= hitVal;
  wa -= hitVal;

  EL_gw.innerHTML = gw;
  EL_wa.innerHTML = wa;
  
}
```

```html
<b>Infantry:</b> <span id="gw">40000</span>
(will stop decreasing if FORT energy is 0 and vice-versa)<br>
<b>Fort:</b> <span id="wall">1000</span> <br>

<button class="troops" onclick="send()">SEND TROOPS</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, it's just that you have a mistake here

```
<span class= id="wall">1000</span></p>
```

Remove the `class=` if you don't need it or add a class.

Regarding your inquiry about value checkers. I created a code snippet to help you out.

```
function send(){
    var labelWall = document.getElementById('wall');
    var labelGW = document.getElementById('gw');
    var wallValue = parseInt(labelWall.innerHTML, 10);
    var GWValue = parseInt(labelGW.innerHTML, 10);
    var b = 500;

    if(wallValue > 0 && GWValue > 0) {
        labelGW.innerHTML = GWValue - b;
        labelWall.innerHTML = wallValue - b;
    }
}
```

[Here's the pen](https://codepen.io/joaquintoral/pen/bRdvVL)

Comment: Thank you for the first part. But after click send troops i dont get an output 39500 and there is yet a if issue

Comment: @urosv, Hello. I thought you could figure it out yourself, but here you go anyway. You don't have to make a lot of code changes. Hope this helps you out. :)

Comment: 1. What is `c` in your example? 2.What if if you have less troops than the wall energy?

Comment: I know that defaults to `10`, but try always to use the radix param with parseInt. Also cache that value instead of parsing twice the same...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan. Thanks man. I updated the code to address your inquiries. If you have anymore to add, please tell me. It helps me out too.